# how to break execution and display error inside success of ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am using ajax call to check for some validation and then submitting the form normally by html. In my ajax call,

```
    function checkId() {
    var str = $("#formObj").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        data : str,
        url : "checkForId.mt",
        async : false,
        success : function(txt) {
            if (txt == "pass") {
                return "true";
            } else if (txt == "same") {
                $("#errorMsgIdSame").removeClass("hidden");
                return "false";
            }
        },
        error : function() {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

If the control goes to "pass", execution should continue. If it goes to "same", the execution should stop. 
I am calling this ajax method from some other method.

```
    function validateForm() {
    var isValid = true;
    isValid = checkId();
    if (!isValid) {
        $("#errorMsg").removeClass("hidden");
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

this validatioForm is called on button click. Now ajax code is working but validateForm method is not taking the return of the ajax method.

Need direction on how to carry this out so that to capture the return from the ajax method and how to return from the ajax method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to return the result of an inner function from an outer function. This definition of `checkId` does just that.

```
function checkId() {
  var result;
  var str = $("#formObj").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type : "post",
    data : str,
    url : "checkForId.mt",
    async : false,
    success : function(txt) {
      if (txt == "pass") {
        result = true;
        return;
      } else if (txt == "same") {
        $("#errorMsgIdSame").removeClass("hidden");
        result = false;
        return;
      }
    },
    error : function() {
      alert("Error");
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Comment: function validateForm() {
    var isValid = true;
    isValid = checkId();  <<<<<---------------
    if (!isValid) {
        $("#errorMsg").removeClass("hidden");
    }
    return isValid;
}    I am not getting any value in the above marked line. If i print it in alert(), i am getting undefined. checkId() is not returning anything when called. But the execution is going in checkId().

Comment: @romhail Can you put a `console.log(txt)`, in the beginning of the `success` function, and verify what result you are getting?

Comment: it is returning "undefined"

Comment: it is returning correct value now. I was returning "true" where as I should have returned only true. Thanks.

Comment: my bad. It is still not working. it is still returning "undefined" when I am setting the return value.   var isValid = true;
    isValid = checkId(); Here when I am doing alert(isValid), it is still printing "undefined".

Comment: ok. removed return from the middle of the ajax call function and put it at the end. Got the flow of an ajax method. Working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

An ajax call is asynchronous.

When you call ajax what is happening is that the ajax starts a new thread to do its task--a post in your case.

After that the code that called the ajax keeps going.

When the task that the ajax call is doing returns, it executes what ever is in its pass or fail sections depending on the task status.

So basically your checkId method completes and returns before the ajax is finished.

I would recommend triggering whatever you need the return value for from the success section or fail section like this:

```
success : function(txt) {
  if (txt == "pass") {
     newfunction(true);
  } else if (txt == "same") {
    $("#errorMsgIdSame").removeClass("hidden");
     newfunction(false);
  }
},
```

Edit:

```
function newfunction(passFail)
{
   //Do something with variable passFail
}
```

Comment: It is a synchronous call if you specify `async : false`

Comment: Ya that is fine and i can call a new method. But I need to return to the old method which is calling this ajax method.